# When using PayPal PDT, does PayPal still send the buyer its own email receipt?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, eclipse-pdt

I have gotten PDT working on my website. When you turn on the PDT setting in your paypal account, I am just wondering if PayPal sends out its own transaction receipt email regardless of whether the auto-return/PDT setting is turned on for my account (and that I may be sending my own email receipt from my app). I believe it does send paypal receipts when auto return / PDT is off.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they will.  You can set all of this up in the sandbox and test it for yourself if you want to confirm.